# In the following code how row_string = " " is working?

Tags: python, string

I am completely new to python, I have the following code and having a hard time understanding line 3 & 6 (double star quoted)!

```
a=5
for row in range(1, a + 1):
    **row_string = ""**
    for column in range(1, a + 1):
        product = row * column
        **row_string += str(product) + "\t"**
    print(row_string)
```

In this code, I didn't understand line 3 and line 6 (double star quoted). Is it possible for someone who can describe me how these lines are executing? If possible elaborately, please. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You understand a `for` loop but not variable assignment?

Comment: What confuses you about those lines?

Comment: It creates an empty string then adds stuff to it, seperated by tabs. Every loop it resets the string.

Comment: This suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @kindall, I do understand the variable assignment, but I didn't understand how this empty string is functioning inside the inner loop!

Comment: @user2357112..I didn't understand how this empty string is functioning inside the inner loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `row_string = ""` in the outer loop creates a new, empty string every time the outer loop runs.

So when the inner loop starts to run, the `row_string` is an empty string. Now each time the inner loop runs, something gets added (appended) to that empty string, namely the value of `product` casted into a string and a tab `\t`. When the inner loop is finished, the whole string gets printed.

Actually `row_string = ""` serves two purposes: first it creates an empty string so you have something to append to. And second it makes sure that every time the inner loop runs, a fresh string is used (so the outer loops are independent of each other)

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like is for each row, we are combining all the column values into one string.

So at the first marked place, we are assigning an empty string to row_string.  This clears out whatever was in it before.

Next, in the second for loop we go through and append "product" and a tab character to row_string.

Once the inner for loop is done, we print the string, then jump back to the top.  Here we clear out the string, and start again on the second row.

So if our table looks like this:

```
red    | blue   | green
purple | yellow | orange
```

our output would look like:

```
red    blue    green
purple    yellow    orange
```

Answer (score 0):

the variable "row_string" is set as an empty variable on line 3 so that the second for loop can create a different column through each iteration. So, python sets the first variable to "1" and adds that same variable to itself 5 times for the first column. Then before the next column is called, the next row is created as "2", so the column iteration can add 2 to itself down the column.